# Dynamically display images in multiple position using single image view

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an image view in my Layout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="340dip"
        android:layout_height="240dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"/>
```

I am setting an `img.setimageresource(R.drawable.apple);`

Now what I need is I have a `i` value which is incrementing in `onclick` of a button as soon as `i` value is incremented, image should be displayed and its is displaying. Again when `i` value is incremented it should display the same image just below the 1st image and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Make another `xml` having `Imageview` only. and remove this `Imageview` from parent xml. Now use `inflater` to inflate the imageview xml and add this `view` in parent xml's layout.

**`EDIT:`**

First make two layouts, `parent` and `child`. Parent layout has only on `linearlayout(vertical)` and child layout has only one `ImageView`. Now Use an `Inflater` like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemServices(Context.Layout_InflaterService);
```

Make a view of child layout like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child,null);
```

Add this view to parent xml's layout.

```
layout.add(view);
```

Hope its clear now.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you please give me any link on that

Comment: you can search it urself on google, i dont know any link but u can try the words like inflater, adding view programmatically...